# Sending data from a GUI to an Arduino nano via USB

Tags: arduino-nano

Can somebody point me in the right direction for information on sending data to an Arduino nano?

My project is to send data that is updated from a GUI (presently written in Python) to an Arduino nano that then makes adjustments to a number of servo motors.

I have the servo code working but am presently using potentiometers to control the servo positions & would like the control done via a GUI.

What libraries would I need to be looking at. Have any of you done anything similar.

Thanks

Nic

Answer (score 1):

Arduino Nano supports FTDI i.e. Virtual Serial Port. So all you have to do is initialize the serial communication using [pySerial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial).

When the data is entered into the GUI, store it in some variables. Send the data in variables to Arduino using Serial Communication. You might have design your own communication protocol on top of Virtual Serial Port in order to identify the data.

You can also use the same library to send the acknowledgement or some data from Arduino to PC, if you want.

Hope this helps you.